# SQL to display name of players who played maximum matches together

Tags: sql

Display the name of players who played maximum matches together. Here Rafal and Nadal should be displayed.

[image]

Comment: tag your dbms as well

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify the db engine you are using, but for example in sql server you could do it like this:

```
select top 1
  case when winner > runner then winner else runner end,
  case when winner < runner then winner else runner end,
  count(*) c
from matches
group by 
  case when winner > runner then winner else runner end,
  case when winner < runner then winner else runner end
order by c desc
```

You can test on this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d3f49080ffd9c122eb221693860e69ed)

The `case when` statements order the names always in the same way. Then, you count the number of times that match happens, and then you order by the count, getting just the first top record.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way:

```
select winner player1, runner player2 from (
select year, winner, runner
from table
union all 
select year, runner, winner
from table
) t 
group by winner, runner 
order by count(distinct year) desc 
limit 1
```